# LINQ queries for complex data organisation

Tags: c#, linq

i have a file that is generated by an external software and i read it into a C# program.
After streamreader had retreiving the file, I made several methods that make the arrangements I need.  Like so :

```
 object[] array = new object[7];

        // THE "WHILE" SPLIT MORE THAN 1 ORDERS FILLED
        // INSERT FILL INFORMATION INTO ARRAY TO POPULATE TABLES
        while (QtyFilled > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fillData.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 4) // check the price
                {
                    array[i] = Math.Round((double)fillData.GetValue(i), prodSpecs.DigitsAfterDecimal);
                }
                else
                {
                    array[i] = fillData.GetValue(i);
                }

                array[5] = 1; // set the fill qty to 1 always
            }

            switch (BuySell)
            {
                case "B":
                    TradeSequenceOrientation += QtyFilled;
                    Table_Buy.Rows.Add(array);

                    // if (Table_Buy.Rows.Count <= 1) break;

                    DataView viewB = new DataView(Table_Buy);
                    viewB.Sort = "Contract ASC, DateExec ASC, TimeExec ASC";
                    Table_Buy = viewB.Table;
                    break;

                case "S":
                    TradeSequenceOrientation -= QtyFilled;
                    Table_Sell.Rows.Add(array);

                    //if (Table_Sell.Rows.Count <= 1) break;

                    DataView viewS = new DataView(Table_Sell);
                    viewS = new DataView(Table_Sell);
                    viewS.Sort = "Contract ASC, DateExec ASC, TimeExec ASC";
                    Table_Sell = viewS.Table;

                    break;
            }

            MERGE_TABLES();

            QtyFilled--;
        }
```

It work's very fine that way but it can optimised. Also, I need to make other queries once the import is established.

For example i need to query if the "Qty" are not the same value when a "buy" and a "sell" is finished (see "Complex queries" on picture). For example you want to buy 10 Qty, and be executed like so 6,2,2. And later, selling is all at once : 10.

```
activity = 6 ;
activity =+ 2 ;
activity =+ 2 ;
activity =- 10 ;

activity == 0;
```

Even if the "Qty" are different, **there is a relationship** between the buy and sell activity until the end, until activity is 0.

**So the final table has to make this particularity appears like "Complex queries" window on picture.**

[PICTURE OF GENERATED TABLES EXAMPLES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxqn9.jpg)

To optimize the code, I'm interested in LINQ queries. I did several tests and I can not get the desired result (as the picture). I am able to use the "where" to display only the relevant products. By cons, I can not seem to merge the lines that resembles the picture. Because I start with queries, I focused on the fact of simple filters, but I find myself quickly blocked because there is a lot of data and it is difficult to always have the same number of lines between purchases and sales.

Here is the code :

```
        var queryBuys = from rowbuy in TableBuys.buyTable.AsEnumerable()
                        where rowbuy.Field<string>("Product") == "CL"
                        select rowbuy;

        var querySells = from rowsell in TableSells.sellTable.AsEnumerable()
                         where rowsell.Field<string>("Product") == "CL"
                         select rowsell;

        Array arrBuy = null;
        Array arrSell = null;

        foreach (var item in queryBuys)
        {
            arrBuy = item.ItemArray.ToArray();
        }

        foreach (var item in querySells)
        {
            arrSell = item.ItemArray.ToArray();
        }

        //Array arrMerge = arrBuy

        foreach (var item in arrBuy)
        {
            trackTable.Rows.Add(arrBuy, arrSell);
        }
```

It will be great if i can have examples of queries wich can do the job directly after the streamreader. My goal is to make the final table look like a combination of the "big B & C" sections on the picture.

[PICTURE OF THE FINAL RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8W5V.jpg)

Thanks for helps,

Comment: I don't think there is a single query that wold do the job.  You have what is know as a "Packing Problem" where buy/sell quantities aren't the same so you have to pack the items to get the quantities to match.  The Romans 2000 years ago couldn't solve the problem when trying to pack their chariots going to war, and mathematicians today still don't have the ideal solution.

Comment: Thanks for reply jdweng, i know that it can be a real headache to achieve this. As I mentioned, I have already done it with many methods, and because I really want the code to be optimized, I need to save lines with queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
Id  Product B/S Qty Price   Order Time  Trans ID
1   FDAX    B   1   9933    08:50:31:405    2818572289
2   FDAX    B   1   9932    08:50:31:407    2818572290
3   FDAX    B   1   9931    08:50:31:408    2818572291
4   FDAX    B   1   9923    08:50:31:409    2818572292
5   FDAX    B   1   9922    08:50:31:409    2818572293
6   FDAX    B   1   9921    08:50:31:410    2818572294
7   FDAX    S   1   9924    08:54:10:720    2818572295
8   FDAX    B   1   9921    08:54:55:058    2818572296
9   FDAX    S   1   9924    08:55:11:229    2818572297
10  FDAX    S   1   9925    08:54:11:001    2818572298
11  FDAX    S   1   9926    08:54:11:400    2818572299
12  FDAX    S   1   9934    08:52:11:384    2818572300
13  FDAX    S   1   9935    08:52:11:673    2818572301
14  FDAX    S   1   9936    08:52:12:169    2818572302
15  FDAX    B   1   9933    08:59:59:800    2818572303
16  FDAX    B   1   9932    08:59:59:802    2818572304
17  FDAX    B   1   9931    08:59:59:803    2818572305
18  FDAX    B   1   9923    08:59:59:804    2818572306
19  FDAX    B   1   9922    08:59:59:804    2818572307
20  FDAX    B   1   9921    08:59:59:805    2818572308
21  FDAX    B   1   9913    08:59:59:806    2818572309
22  FDAX    B   1   9912    08:59:59:807    2818572310
23  FDAX    B   1   9911    08:59:59:807    2818572311
24  FDAX    S   1   9914    09:00:54:354    2818572312
25  FDAX    S   1   9915    09:00:54:249    2818572313
26  FDAX    B   1   9912    09:00:55:804    2818572314
27  FDAX    B   1   9911    09:00:54:858    2818572315
28  FDAX    S   1   9914    09:01:08:656    2818572316
29  FDAX    S   1   9915    09:01:08:605    2818572317
30  FDAX    S   1   9916    09:00:52:749    2818572318
31  FDAX    B   1   9913    09:01:14:151    2818572319
32  FDAX    S   1   9916    09:01:26:952    2818572320
33  FDAX    S   1   9924    09:00:13:048    2818572321
34  FDAX    S   1   9925    09:00:12:908    2818572322
35  FDAX    S   1   9926    09:00:12:892    2818572323
36  FDAX    B   1   9923    09:02:00:910    2818572324
37  FDAX    B   1   9922    09:01:58:463    2818572325
38  FDAX    B   1   9921    09:01:56:272    2818572326
39  FDAX    S   1   9924    09:02:08:309    2818572327
40  FDAX    S   1   9925    09:02:07:911    2818572328
41  FDAX    S   1   9926    09:02:07:260    2818572329
42  FDAX    B   1   9923    09:02:20:215    2818572330
43  FDAX    B   1   9922    09:02:19:709    2818572331
44  FDAX    B   1   9921    09:02:19:248    2818572332
45  FDAX    B   1   9913    09:01:32:103    2818572333
46  FDAX    B   1   9912    09:01:12:646    2818572334
47  FDAX    B   1   9911    09:01:11:437    2818572335
48  FDAX    S   1   9914    09:03:16:865    2818572336
49  FDAX    S   1   9915    09:03:07:814    2818572337
50  FDAX    S   1   9916    09:03:07:262    2818572338
51  FDAX    S   1   9924    09:02:27:563    2818572339
52  FDAX    B   1   9921    09:04:07:069    2818572340
53  FDAX    B   1   9913    09:04:04:916    2818572341
54  FDAX    B   1   9912    09:04:04:771    2818572342
55  FDAX    B   1   9911    09:03:55:669    2818572343
56  FDAX    B   1   9903    08:59:59:808    2818572344
57  FDAX    B   1   9902    08:59:59:810    2818572345
58  FDAX    B   1   9901    08:59:59:811    2818572346
59  FDAX    S   1   9904    09:05:06:345    2818572347
60  FDAX    S   1   9905    09:05:06:329    2818572348
61  FDAX    S   1   9906    09:05:00:128    2818572349
62  FDAX    B   1   9903    09:05:24:026    2818572350
63  FDAX    B   1   9902    09:05:21:176    2818572351
64  FDAX    B   1   9901    09:05:20:854    2818572352
65  FDAX    S   1   9897    09:05:54:177    2818572353
66  FDAX    S   1   9898    09:05:54:179    2818572354
67  FDAX    S   1   9899    09:05:54:180    2818572355
68  FDAX    S   1   9904    09:05:34:107    2818572356
69  FDAX    S   1   9905    09:05:28:125    2818572357
70  FDAX    S   1   9906    09:05:26:208    2818572358
71  FDAX    S   1   9907    09:05:54:181    2818572359
72  FDAX    S   1   9908    09:05:54:182    2818572360
73  FDAX    S   1   9909    09:05:54:183    2818572361
74  FDAX    S   1   9914    09:04:25:325    2818572362
75  FDAX    S   1   9915    09:04:25:009    2818572363
76  FDAX    S   1   9916    09:04:23:920    2818572364
77  FDAX    S   1   9917    09:05:54:185    2818572365
78  FDAX    S   1   9918    09:05:54:189    2818572366
79  FDAX    B   1   9915    09:06:34:083    2818572367
80  FDAX    B   1   9914    09:06:33:534    2818572368
81  FDAX    B   1   9913    09:06:32:411    2818572369
82  FDAX    B   1   9912    09:06:31:571    2818572370
83  FDAX    B   1   9911    09:06:30:766    2818572371
84  FDAX    S   1   9914    09:06:42:377    2818572372
85  FDAX    S   1   9915    09:06:41:334    2818572373
86  FDAX    S   1   9916    09:06:38:232    2818572374
87  FDAX    S   1   9917    09:06:37:932    2818572375
88  FDAX    S   1   9918    09:06:36:162    2818572376
89  FDAX    S   1   9919    09:05:54:190    2818572377
90  FDAX    S   1   9924    09:04:10:035    2818572378
91  FDAX    B   1   9923    09:07:56:075    2818572379
92  FDAX    B   1   9922    09:07:56:088    2818572380
93  FDAX    B   1   9921    09:07:55:233    2818572381
94  FDAX    B   1   9916    09:07:40:520    2818572382
95  FDAX    B   1   9915    09:07:39:634    2818572383
96  FDAX    B   1   9914    09:07:34:815    2818572384
97  FDAX    B   1   9913    09:07:34:017    2818572385
98  FDAX    B   1   9912    09:07:32:416    2818572386
99  FDAX    B   1   9911    09:06:45:284    2818572387
100 FDAX    B   1   9906    09:06:24:879    2818572388
101 FDAX    B   1   9905    09:06:24:789    2818572389
102 FDAX    B   1   9904    09:06:24:722    2818572390
103 FDAX    S   1   9907    09:08:35:328    2818572391
104 FDAX    S   1   9908    09:08:34:286    2818572392
105 FDAX    S   1   9909    09:08:34:097    2818572393
106 FDAX    S   1   9914    09:08:16:172    2818572394
107 FDAX    S   1   9915    09:08:15:826    2818572395
108 FDAX    S   1   9916    09:08:15:219    2818572396
109 FDAX    S   1   9917    09:08:14:824    2818572397
110 FDAX    S   1   9918    09:08:12:475    2818572398
111 FDAX    S   1   9919    09:08:12:191    2818572399
112 FDAX    B   1   9916    09:09:47:646    2818572400
113 FDAX    B   1   9915    09:09:45:932    2818572401
114 FDAX    S   1   9918    09:09:59:109    2818572402
115 FDAX    S   1   9919    09:09:58:345    2818572403
116 FDAX    S   1   9924    09:08:06:197    2818572404
117 FDAX    S   1   9925    09:02:24:615    2818572405
118 FDAX    S   1   9926    09:02:22:114    2818572406
119 FDAX    S   1   9927    09:05:54:191    2818572407
120 FDAX    S   1   9928    09:05:54:192    2818572408
121 FDAX    S   1   9929    09:05:54:192    2818572409
122 FDAX    B   1   9926    09:10:41:350    2818572410
123 FDAX    B   1   9925    09:10:39:783    2818572411
124 FDAX    B   1   9924    09:10:35:048    2818572412
125 FDAX    S   1   9927    09:11:09:134    2818572413
126 FDAX    S   1   9928    09:11:00:210    2818572414
127 FDAX    S   1   9929    09:10:59:733    2818572415
128 FDAX    S   1   9934    09:00:02:291    2818572416
129 FDAX    S   1   9935    09:00:02:099    2818572417
130 FDAX    S   1   9936    09:00:01:647    2818572418
131 FDAX    B   1   9933    09:11:55:096    2818572419
132 FDAX    B   1   9933    09:11:55:141    2818572419
133 FDAX    B   1   9932    09:11:55:092    2818572420
134 FDAX    B   1   9931    09:11:54:797    2818572421
135 FDAX    S   1   9934    09:13:08:747    2818572422
136 FDAX    S   1   9935    09:13:07:692    2818572423
137 FDAX    S   1   9936    09:13:05:151    2818572424
138 FDAX    B   1   9933    09:13:20:091    2818572425
139 FDAX    B   1   9932    09:13:12:943    2818572426
140 FDAX    B   1   9931    09:13:12:761    2818572427
141 FDAX    S   1   9934    09:13:28:213    2818572428
142 FDAX    S   1   9935    09:13:27:910    2818572429
143 FDAX    S   1   9936    09:13:05:155    2818572430
144 FDAX    S   1   9936    09:13:24:895    2818572431
145 FDAX    B   1   9933    09:14:52:499    2818572432
146 FDAX    B   1   9933    09:14:52:557    2818572433
147 FDAX    B   1   9932    09:14:51:856    2818572434
148 FDAX    B   1   9931    09:14:51:772    2818572435
149 FDAX    S   1   9934    09:15:07:276    2818572436
150 FDAX    B   1   9931    09:15:55:273    2818572437
151 FDAX    S   1   9934    09:16:01:129    2818572438
152 FDAX    S   1   9935    09:15:07:200    2818572439
153 FDAX    S   1   9936    09:15:05:999    2818572440
154 FDAX    S   1   9936    09:15:07:099    2818572441
155 FDAX    B   1   9933    09:16:14:777    2818572442
156 FDAX    B   1   9933    09:16:15:071    2818572442
157 FDAX    B   1   9932    09:16:13:655    2818572443
158 FDAX    B   1   9931    09:16:13:555    2818572444
159 FDAX    B   1   9926    09:11:23:599    2818572445
160 FDAX    B   1   9925    09:11:21:360    2818572446
161 FDAX    B   1   9924    09:11:15:430    2818572447
162 FDAX    S   1   9927    09:18:04:286    2818572448
163 FDAX    S   1   9928    09:18:02:434    2818572449
164 FDAX    B   1   9925    09:18:18:535    2818572450
165 FDAX    S   1   9928    09:18:27:235    2818572451
166 FDAX    B   1   9925    09:18:36:124    2818572452
167 FDAX    B   1   9924    09:18:10:516    2818572453
168 FDAX    B   1   9923    09:10:30:634    2818572454
169 FDAX    S   1   9926    09:18:42:283    2818572455
170 FDAX    S   1   9927    09:18:42:120    2818572456
171 FDAX    S   1   9928    09:18:41:328    2818572457
172 FDAX    S   1   9929    09:18:01:430    2818572458
173 FDAX    S   1   9934    09:17:07:233    2818572459
174 FDAX    S   1   9935    09:17:06:658    2818572460
175 FDAX    S   1   9936    09:17:05:276    2818572461
176 FDAX    S   1   9936    09:17:05:273    2818572462
177 FDAX    B   1   9933    09:18:53:729    2818572463
178 FDAX    B   1   9933    09:18:55:020    2818572464
179 FDAX    B   1   9932    09:18:53:186    2818572465
180 FDAX    B   1   9931    09:18:53:019    2818572466
181 FDAX    S   1   9934    09:24:42:206    2818572467
182 FDAX    B   1   9931    09:25:04:308    2818572468
183 FDAX    S   1   9934    09:25:10:501    2818572469
184 FDAX    B   1   9931    09:25:22:221    2818572470
185 FDAX    B   1   9926    09:18:52:391    2818572471
186 FDAX    B   1   9925    09:18:52:389    2818572472
187 FDAX    B   1   9924    09:18:52:229    2818572473
188 FDAX    B   1   9923    09:18:51:117    2818572474
189 FDAX    B   1   9922    09:10:30:630    2818572475
190 FDAX    B   1   9921    09:10:29:341    2818572476
191 FDAX    S   1   9987    09:47:50:537    2818572477
192 FDAX    S   1   9988    09:47:50:538    2818572478
193 FDAX    B   1   9985    09:47:52:796    2818572479
194 FDAX    B   1   9984    09:47:50:983    2818572480
195 FDAX    B   1   10103   10:38:26:987    2818572481
196 FDAX    B   1   10102   10:38:26:988    2818572482
197 FDAX    B   1   10101   10:38:26:989    2818572483
198 FDAX    S   1   10104   10:38:29:657    2818572484
199 FDAX    S   1   10105   10:38:27:226    2818572485
200 FDAX    B   1   10102   10:38:35:672    2818572486
201 FDAX    B   1   10101   10:38:35:031    2818572487
202 FDAX    S   1   10104   10:38:42:319    2818572488
203 FDAX    B   1   10101   10:39:45:325    2818572489
204 FDAX    S   1   10104   10:39:50:441    2818572490
205 FDAX    S   1   10105   10:38:39:128    2818572491
206 FDAX    S   1   10106   10:38:27:143    2818572492
207 FDAX    B   1   10123   10:40:05:641    2818572493
208 FDAX    B   1   10122   10:40:05:645    2818572494
209 FDAX    B   1   10121   10:40:05:646    2818572495
210 FDAX    S   1   10124   10:40:05:983    2818572496
211 FDAX    S   1   10125   10:40:05:862    2818572497
212 FDAX    S   1   10126   10:40:05:751    2818572498
213 FDAX    S   1   10097   10:54:09:339    2818572499
214 FDAX    S   1   10098   10:54:09:339    2818572500
215 FDAX    S   1   10099   10:54:09:340    2818572501
216 FDAX    B   1   10103   11:00:32:571    2818572502
217 FDAX    B   1   10102   11:00:32:574    2818572503
218 FDAX    B   1   10101   11:00:32:575    2818572504
219 FDAX    B   1   10096   11:00:05:366    2818572505
220 FDAX    B   1   10095   11:00:04:186    2818572506
221 FDAX    B   1   10094   11:00:04:125    2818572507
222 FDAX    B   1   10093   11:00:32:577    2818572508
223 FDAX    S   1   10096   11:01:28:144    2818572509
224 FDAX    S   1   10097   11:01:19:041    2818572510
225 FDAX    S   1   10098   11:01:11:180    2818572511
226 FDAX    S   1   10099   11:01:10:373    2818572512
227 FDAX    B   1   10096   11:01:53:906    2818572513
228 FDAX    B   1   10095   11:01:52:809    2818572514
229 FDAX    S   1   10098   11:02:02:999    2818572515
230 FDAX    S   1   10099   11:01:58:898    2818572516
231 FDAX    S   1   10104   11:01:01:833    2818572517
232 FDAX    S   1   10105   11:00:52:336    2818572518
233 FDAX    S   1   10106   11:00:52:174    2818572519
234 FDAX    S   1   10107   10:54:09:341    2818572520
235 FDAX    S   1   10108   10:54:09:342    2818572521
236 FDAX    S   1   10109   10:54:09:344    2818572522
237 FDAX    B   1   10106   11:03:17:905    2818572523
238 FDAX    S   1   10109   11:05:18:444    2818572524
239 FDAX    B   1   10106   11:05:28:347    2818572525
240 FDAX    B   1   10105   11:03:08:102    2818572526
241 FDAX    B   1   10104   11:03:04:449    2818572527
242 FDAX    B   1   10103   11:02:49:001    2818572528
243 FDAX    B   1   10103   11:02:57:435    2818572529
244 FDAX    B   1   10102   11:02:48:992    2818572530
245 FDAX    B   1   10101   11:02:48:951    2818572531
246 FDAX    S   1   10100.5 11:07:15:254    2818572532
247 FDAX    S   1   10097   11:15:56:429    2818572533
248 FDAX    S   1   10098   11:15:56:431    2818572534
249 FDAX    B   1   10095   11:16:58:076    2818572535
250 FDAX    B   1   10094   11:16:16:236    2818572536
251 FDAX    S   1   10097   11:17:11:586    2818572537
252 FDAX    B   1   10094   11:17:32:123    2818572538
253 FDAX    S   1   10077   11:20:49:336    2818572539
254 FDAX    S   1   10078   11:20:49:338    2818572540
255 FDAX    B   1   10075   11:20:51:940    2818572541
256 FDAX    B   1   10074   11:20:51:046    2818572542
257 FDAX    S   1   10077   11:20:56:003    2818572543
258 FDAX    S   1   10078   11:20:54:987    2818572544
259 FDAX    B   1   10075   11:22:04:341    2818572545
260 FDAX    B   1   10074   11:21:38:046    2818572546
261 FDAX    S   1   10077   11:23:40:165    2818572547
262 FDAX    S   1   10078   11:23:28:766    2818572548
263 FDAX    S   1   10079   11:20:49:339    2818572549
264 FDAX    B   1   10076   11:25:50:570    2818572550
265 FDAX    B   1   10075   11:24:29:670    2818572551
266 FDAX    B   1   10074   11:24:27:567    2818572552
267 FDAX    S   1   10077   11:26:15:631    2818572553
268 FDAX    B   1   10074   11:28:03:728    2818572554
269 FDAX    S   1   10077   11:28:26:637    2818572555
270 FDAX    S   1   10078   11:26:04:917    2818572556
271 FDAX    B   1   10075   11:28:33:779    2818572557
272 FDAX    S   1   10078   11:28:38:372    2818572558
273 FDAX    S   1   10079   11:26:04:272    2818572559
274 FDAX    B   1   10076   11:29:24:189    2818572560
275 FDAX    B   1   10075   11:28:51:038    2818572561
299 CL  B   1   4133    13:44:25:408    2818572585
300 CL  B   1   4132    13:44:25:466    2818572586
301 CL  B   1   4131    13:44:25:468    2818572587
302 CL  S   1   4134    13:45:12:120    2818572588
303 CL  S   1   4135    13:45:06:315    2818572589
304 CL  S   1   4136    13:44:37:648    2818572590
305 CL  B   1   4133    13:49:10:858    2818572591
306 CL  S   1   4136    13:49:21:997    2818572592
307 CL  B   1   4133    14:15:35:825    2818572593
308 CL  B   1   4132    14:15:35:827    2818572594
309 CL  B   1   4131    14:15:35:828    2818572595
310 CL  B   1   4123    14:15:35:830    2818572596
311 CL  B   1   4122    14:15:35:834    2818572597
312 CL  S   1   4125    14:17:02:631    2818572598
313 CL  S   1   4126    14:16:54:376    2818572599
314 CL  S   1   4134    14:16:53:651    2818572600
315 CL  S   1   4135    14:16:53:641    2818572601
316 CL  S   1   4131    14:17:40:481    2818572602
```

Comment: Links have to be like this :

1) check names of all product to make a list.

2) check the name of a product to make them match with the other side according to B/S and Qty.
ex :  (FDAX, B , 1) need a (FDAX, S , 1) on the other side.

if the exit is uncompleted :
ex :  (FDAX, B , 3) need a (FDAX, S , 1) on the other side and search later for others match.
...etc.